# If the application closes WCF-Client connection

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

We have one WCF Service hosted on IIS and there is an WebApp the calls the WCF Service using BasicBinding.

The Service hangs from time to time, I think after a large number of calls.

Sine we host both the WCF Service and the WebApp, is it possible to check if the WebApp closes the connection with the Service.

I am thinking any tool out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question was never my intention. Anyway, I'v fond a very good tool called TCPView.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

I run in on same Server as my WCf Service and could see the list of all open connections.

Best Ragreds